# "Unfortunately GeoQuiz has stopped"

Tags: java, android

This is the error I am getting

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz, PID: 7499

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz/com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity}: **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference**
```

This is my code:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);

        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I have no clue why I'm getting this error. I thought I assigned the object reference well and I checked the punctuation to make sure.

This is my XML code if that helps with the buttons and the ids.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation= "vertical"
    tools:context="com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/question_text" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding = "24dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Ok so I wanted to try and check if the values were null or not and I put these two lines of code to check

```
System.out.println("mTrueButtonIsNull:" +(mTrueButton==null));
System.out.println("mFalseButtonIsNull:" +(mFalseButton==null));
```

and I got back true and I don't know why or what I have to do now.

```
5-27 18:11:10.266 20014-20014/com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz I/System.out: mTrueButtonIsNull:true
05-27 18:11:10.266 20014-20014/com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz I/System.out: mFalseButtonIsNull:true
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a problem with one of your Buttons. which is defined as `null`.

Make sure you have `true_button` and `false_button` inside the `activity_quiz` layout.

If there is no problem with your layout file, Clean and re-build your app.

Comment: Then try to clean and re-build your project.

Comment: The ids were created in the XML file and I used them in the java file correctly right? I don't understand why I'm getting null back as a result. And how would I clean and re-build the project?

Comment: In Android Studio go to `Build > Clean Project` or `Build > Rebuild Project` .. And If you're using eclipse `Project -> clean`. re-run the project again after clean.